# How do I drop the css style from the fieldset labels when the user has hovered over the labels for the first time?

Tags: javascript, css, styles, rating

I have the below fiddle for my fieldset star rating selector:

https://jsfiddle.net/bxd107gv/

It's designed to default to 5 stars but the user can then click one to amend the selection to a lesser value if appropriate but; I think the style:

```
.rating > label{
    color:#FFD700;
}
```

Is interfering by applying that so I tried doing a mouseover event in JS to set the star back to it's default colour but that has the exact same issue but with a different colour; how do I amend this so that only the stars that are selected are highlighted yellow and the rest are grey after the user changes from 5 stars to any other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the container to mark the rated status when rating, and add an additional rated css to the label in the rated container:

1. Add the following javascript to the function setRating which you handle the rating logic

```
document.getElementById('starRatingSelection').classList.add('rated');
```

2. Add the following css at the end of you css file

```
.rated > label{
  color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

Comment: Ignore that last comment - this now sort of works but once you change from say the default 5 stars to 3 stars, if they then tried to go to 2 stars it wont work

Comment: @Lombard You can try to set the same `name` attribute to all the radio input element, such as `name="rating"`

Comment: Yes of course I'm such an idiot for missing this! Solution works perfectly it was my own lack of forethought.

Comment: @Lombard Lol, it's all right, carelessness is common.